# Why my column chart is getting cropped in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I have implemented column chart using highchart .

My rightmost column is getting cropped and I am not able to get it fixed .
Please suggest which option is being missed by me .

```
{

"chart":{

      "renderTo":"1_123456_id",
      "type":"column",
      "marginBottom":100,
      "marginTop":100,
      "marginRight":400,
      "width":1050
},
"leftMetric":"Too Soft",
"rightMetric":"Too Loud",
"activeCount":8,
"passiveCount":0,
"optimal":92,
"totalResponses":25,
"averageText":"4.6",
"plotOptions":{

      "series":{
         "pointWidth":[
            "30"
         ],
         "borderRadius":[
            "10"
         ],

      },
      "column":{
         "pointPlacement":"on",    
      },
},
"credits":{

"enabled":false
},
"title":{

      "text":"VOLUME",
      "x":310,
      "align":"left",
      "style":{
         "fontWeight":"bold",
         "fontSize":15,
         "color":"#000",
         "marginRight":100
      }
},
"xAxis":[

      {
         "categories":[
            0,
            0,
            0,
            1,
            0,
            20,
            2,
            0,
            1,
            1,
            0
         ],
         "tickmarkPlacement":"on",
         "tickPositions":[
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10,
            11
         ],
         "gridLineDashStyle":"longdash",
         "gridLineWidth":1,
         "labels":{
            "style":{
               "fontWeight":"bold",
               "fontSize":15
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "linkedTo":0,
         "tickmarkPlacement":"on",
         "tickPositions":[
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10,
            11
         ],
         "opposite":"true",
         "categories":[
            0,
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            4,
            3,
            2,
            1,
            0
         ],
         "gridLineDashStyle":"longdash",
         "gridLineWidth":1
      }
],
"yAxis":{

      "min":0,
      "max":30,
      "labels":{
         "enabled":true
      },
      "title":{
         "text":"Responses"
      },
      "tickInterval":2,
      "gridLineColor":"#9ACD9D",
},
"series":[

{

         "showInLegend":false,
         "name":"speaker",
         "data":[
            {
               "y":0,
               "color":"C82506"
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "color":"BC5B0C"
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "color":"F39019"
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "color":"F5D329"
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "color":"#70BF40"
            },
            {
               "y":20,
               "color":"#01882A"
            },
            {
               "y":2,
               "color":"#70BF40"
            },
            {
               "y":0,
               "color":"F5D329"
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "color":"F39019"
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "color":"BC5B0C"
            },
            {
               "y":1,
               "color":"C82506"
            }
         ]
      }
]
}
```

[**LINK TO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ASJm9/4/)

**EDIT**
How can make grid lines to move out of axis on extremes and middle as marked in image[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Correct way:**
you just need to turn off `clip` in `plotOptions`

```
plotOptions:{
      column: {
         pointPlacement: "on",
         clip: false,
      }
}
```

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/saeed_parsaee/ASJm9/10/) and also Thanks to [Pawel Fus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451635/pawel-fus)

---

**Tricky way:**
Here is what you want. i don't update my previous answer as that may help others.
but as the problem was **charts cropped by highchart** so i do the reverse and remove the integer number from `clip-path= "url(#highcharts-`**`NUMBER`**`)` attribute to have the full chart.

```
<g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="3" transform="translate(51,100) scale(1 1)" style="" clip-path="url(#highcharts-1)">
```

Here the code to do this:

```
function showMagic(){
    $(".highcharts-series-group").children()
        .filter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var lol = $this.attr("clip-path");
        if (lol) {
            $this.attr("clip-path","url(#highcharts)");
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
window.onload = showMagic;
```

Yes a little tricky, but it works! Here is the [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ASJm9/9/)

---

### UPDATE:

This part will be the answer to the update part of question:
we should format labels of `xAxis` :

```
 "labels": { 
      "useHTML": true,
      "formatter": function () {

            if(this.value==0 || this.value==5)
            {
                return '<p style="margin-top: -20px;" >'+this.value + '<br> | </p> ' ;
            }
          else
          {
              return this.value;
          }
        }
  },
```

Here is the [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/saeed_parsaee/ASJm9/17/)

Comment: Personally I don't advice to edit generated code by Highcharts. It's better to overwrite function which generate that clipPath instead.

Comment: @PawełFus Yes you are 100% right and I tried to do so, but i wasn't able So i had to chose the shortcut way :)

Comment: Clip rect is created in `drawChartBox` - so overwrite that function with removing that clip. Or when series rendered, in `animate` you can remove `clip()` function.

Comment: @PawełFus i found something that i never saw before. the solution was two words `clip: false,` in the `plotOptions`. see the updated answer

Comment: @osyan Its strange that I can't find that  option in highchart api .

Comment: @osyan. Need little more help from you . Can I make the grid line to move out of axis as marked section in image. See my edited post .

Comment: @Let'sCode that,s a good option that they didn,t cover in their documents. And about other question i should say there is nothing imposible. but its hard one i think. because you should extend the tick plus changing the number Y position. but if i find something i'll let you know.

Comment: @Let'sCode Checkout this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saeed_parsaee/ASJm9/17/ . if it is 99% of what you want, tell me to update my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `pointPlacement: "on"`. so just remove this part of yor code:

```
"column":{
         "pointPlacement":"on",    
      },
```

When pointPlacement is "on", the point will not create any padding of the X axis In a column chart.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASJm9/5/)

Comment: I have used that option because I want to hide the grid lines that are outside the tick points .How can I achieve that effect if I remove 'pointPlacement'?

Comment: This is the way `"pointPlacement":"on"` works. you have one option to draw your charts between the ticks. when `"pointPlacement": "between"`, the columns will be laid out between ticks. but i don't think you want that too. so lets walk around and find a tricky solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924994/how-to-customize-highcharts-for-this-graph . This question has the reference graph I am  trying to achive as you can see there is no padding on x axis on reference graph so I was trying to achieve that .

Comment: @Let'sCode i have find a tricky solution for you. just working on that. i'll post it when it's done!

Answer (score 0):

First remove tickPositions, they are unnecessary when using categories. Then you need to set:

- `min`: -0.5
- `max`: categories.length - 0.5 (10.5 in your case)
- `startOnTick`: false
- `endOnTick`: false

And live example: http://jsfiddle.net/ASJm9/7/

Comment: Need little more help from you . Can I make the grid line to move out of axis as marked section in image. See my edited post .

Comment: I think that better idea is to remove top padding, and then just render texts inside the chart. Anyway, why don't you use plotBands for this?